# Different behavior when I must open app from URL

Tags: android, hyperlink

I've noticed different behavior when I tap on an URL to open my app. When I test it like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.asd.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/test"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

it works fine and open the app. But when I have to put the real URL:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.asd.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/?goto=login"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

it doesn't work and open the browser! I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 and Android 4.4.2

Note the difference in the `android:pathPrefix`

Comment: because `?goto=login` is not a path ... on API >= 19  you can use `android:ssp(*)`

Comment: aff. What I can do? URL's will come like that

Comment: hmmm, [android:ssp(*) is not documented](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-ssp-data-intent-filter/) ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, like Selvin mentioned in the comments, "?goto=logo" is not a path, it's a parameter appended to the end of the path. Now, if that was something restful, like "/login", then your approach would work fine.

But, since it's not... One solution would be to allow the app to open all URLs in your domain, and then determine what to do with them once you're inside your app. If the path (well, in your case, parameters) can be handled, then redirect them internally. If the path can't be handled, redirect them via a WebView inside your app that still maintains your app's themes.

You could do that like:

```
<data
    android:host="www.asd.com"
    android:pathPattern=".*"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

Then, basically, in your launcher Activity, you would call getIntent().getData() to get the URI your Activity was launched with. If it's not null, parse out the params. If you find params that your app can handle, then do that. If not, you can redirect them to a WebView to not ruin their experience.

E.g. to get the URL without the domain in it, you could parse it crudely like so:

```
private String getUrlWithoutDomain(Uri data){
    String uri = data.toString();
    return uri.substring(uri.indexOf("/", 9) + 1); // 9 because it will start searching for the bounding / after https:// and the first letters of your domain
}
```

Then you can get all the parameters you've appended to the URL with something like:

```
private String[][] getParams(String pathAfterDomain){
    String params = pathAfterDomain.substring(pathAfterDomain.indexOf("?"));
    String[] unfilteredParams = params.split("&");

    String[][] filteredParams = new String[unfilteredParams.length][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < filteredParams.length; i++) filteredParams[i] = unfilteredParams[i].split("=");
    return filteredParams;
}
```

Which would return a multidimensional String array containing a list of params, where the first item in the secondary array is the key and the second item is the value.

In this case, `filteredParams[0][0]` would be "goto" and `filteredParams[0][1]` would be "login".

Then, all you have to do is check for the existence of params that you can handle and deal with them accordingly.

Note: If using the above methods, make sure the URI isn't null and actually contains parameters before entering those methods, else they will fail with some NPEs.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: OMG! why are you reinventing the wheel? `String goto = data.getQueryParameter("goto");`

Comment: Selvin, you're a godsend and I think I love you.

Comment: Thanks both for your help, but Android doesn't like the URL with parameters, only path's like "www.asd.com/login" are valids. Thanks. I had to change the incoming URL's